# Can a single CT Clamp go to 2 energy meters?

Tags: solar-energy, power-measurement, clamp, ct

I have a Split Core CT CTSA016 - 100A/50mA Yuanxing CT Clamp[(Datasheet is here)](https://www.tichenassociates.com/documents/CTSA016_DataSheet_UL.pdf) around my mains - and it is feeding into my Solar Inverter.

I have just purchased a Shelly EM 2 Channel WiFi energy meter to be able to access more easily and directly the power use of my electricity supply.

I am wondering, can I connect the positive and negative feed from that CT Clamp to both my Shelly Em Energy Meter, and also the Solar Inverter?

Comment: Please link a data sheet for the CT.

Comment: what do you mean by `split the positive and negative feed`?

Comment: I mean, currently the 2 wires coming from the CT Clamp, are going into a connector, and then through a long cable and into the Inverter. I am wondering, can I also put into that connector a second set of cables to also feed into another energy meter?

Comment: I have added a datasheet link @Andyaka

Comment: You would need to have specific knowlege of how the solar inverter and the Shelly device implement their inputs. It may work, but then again, it may not. The simplest solution is to have separate CTs.